# How to display an array of objects in a table in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, mapping, setstate

I have recently been learning react. I set my state to an array of objects. I want to display that array in a table on the page (each object on one line). I have been researching map, however I'm having a bit of trouble understanding it. I was able to use map just fine at a different place in my code to map through an **array**, but I am having trouble mapping through an **array of objects**. This code takes place in the div inside my render:

```
<table>
  {this.state.orderDetails.map((item =>
  <tr key={item}>{item}</tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

I am getting this error: 'Unhandled Rejection (Error): Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {OrderID, CustomerID, AddressID, Date, ItemID, BookID, UnitPrice, Quantity}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.'

Order details has definitely been set correctly; when I open my react tools and check the state in this component, it is listed as an array with two elements, each element being an object with multiple elements within. How can I successfully map through this array of objects and display it in table form (with each object on its own row)? Thanks is advance for any ideas!!!

***EDIT***
After taking some advice from the answers and comments, I have changed my map to the following:

```
<table>
  {this.state.orderDetails.map((item =>
  <tr><td key={item.OrderID}>{item.CustomerID}</td></tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

The error has gone away. However, when I click the button, I get one tiny table cell that is empty. I would expect multiple cells since my array has two objects, and of course I would expect it not to be empty. Also, I am wanting to display more than just customerID. I have several elements in each object that I want to render on the table (ex. quantity, price, title, etc...). Any further sugesstions?

Comment: what is your object structure? try outputting the name or other display property `<tr key={item.id}>{item.name}</tr>`

Comment: When mapping array of objects, each object is passed to the `item`.  To access the content of the object, you can use `item.property` where property is the property youwant to access. In your case I think it would be something like `<tr key={item.OrderID}>{item.Quantity}</tr>` <- This will print each row with the quantity property and OrderID as key.

Comment: Try to do: `<tr key={item.id}><OrderRow order={item} /></tr>` and create an Order component: `function Order({order})=><><td>{order.name}...other columns</>`

Comment: Take a look at my answer it should do the trick - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61557412/9792594 - would be great if you could provide your state (array of objects), I had to guess.

Answer (score 10):

We don't know what your array of objects look like so we have to guess:

So I guess this input:

```js
const initState = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", quantitiy: 50 },
    { id: 2, name: "milk", quantitiy: 20 },
    { id: 3, name: "water", quantitiy: 10 }
  ];
```

And I get this output:

[image]

It's completely flexible so if we have input:

```js
const initState = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", quantitiy: 50, location: "cupboard" },
    { id: 2, name: "milk", quantitiy: 20, location: "fridge" },
    { id: 3, name: "water", quantitiy: 10, location: "fridge" }
  ];
```

Then we get this output:

[image]

The most important thing is to map over the object values inside the map which maps over the state array:

```js
{state.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item).map((val) => (
            <td>{val}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
```

full demo below and on codePen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/zYvEbML

I used a functional component but it would be very similar with a class-based component.

NOTE: you could also create a row component and then call that component inside the map over the state array. Inside this row component, you would map of the Object keys like I did and output table data elements. It's a balance between death by component (i.e. breaking down everything into smaller and smaller components nested inside each other) and fewer components which are too complex.

```js
function MyTable() {
  const initState = [
    { id: 1, name: "bread", quantitiy: 50, location: "cupboard" },
    { id: 2, name: "milk", quantitiy: 20, location: "fridge" },
    { id: 3, name: "water", quantitiy: 10, location: "fridge" }
  ];
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(initState);

  return (
    <table>
      <tr key={"header"}>
        {Object.keys(state[0]).map((key) => (
          <th>{key}</th>
        ))}
      </tr>
      {state.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          {Object.values(item).map((val) => (
            <td>{val}</td>
          ))}
        </tr>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyTable />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

```css
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="target"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

item is an object from the array. So this object will have key(s) and value(s). You need to retrive those and show

For example suppose array is like

```
orderDetails=[{
  OrderID:1,
  CustomerID:'someName'
}]
```

Then in map you need to do

```
<table>
  {this.state.orderDetails.map((item =>
  <tr key={item.OrderID}>{item.CustomerID}</tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

Comment: I made this adjustment. The error goes away, but no table renders on the page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

> Objects are not valid as a React child

It means that you passed an Object instead of something that React can deserialize; string for example, or a number.

First of all, you have to pass to **key={}** something that is unique (not an array index). `itemID` would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this,

```
 <table>
  {this.state.orderDetails.map((item =>
  <tr><td key={item.OrderID}>{item.UnitPrice}</td></tr>
  ))}
</table>
```

Comment: I made this adjustment. The error goes away, but no table renders on the page. Any suggestions?

Comment: First please check what you are getting in `this.state.orderDetails`

Comment: I am getting an array with two objects.