# How to create a table of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I'm a beginner using React to create a website. We are trying to create a table where each row contains different details of information about an object. Specifically, we are trying to create rows like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtHd5.png)

From my perspective, our approach should be to create a list of these entry objects and somehow map their components into each row of a table. It would also be best if the table were not restricted to columns via key/value pairs such as the ones discussed in [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61556179/how-to-display-an-array-of-objects-in-a-table-in-react)

Any advice or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show what you've tried so far? How is your React app organized, what does your data for each row look like, where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can create a list using JSON.

`let list = [{ item : 1 }, { item 2 }];`